# Cannot Running 2 Model in 1 function?

Tags: php, model

I have error is : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

i think there is something that should be included but i don't know what..
please help me...

```
public function index()
{
    $srcProduct = $this->dbAll->showProduct('','');
    $kategori = $this->dbAll->kategori();

    $this->output_data['listProduct'] = $srcProduct;
    $this->output_data['listCategory'] = $kategori;

    $this->load->view('home',$this->output_data);
}
```

Comment: `dbAll`      is single model???yes you can run 2 models and call their functions seperately....

Comment: @goudaElalfy Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @abbas ohh... isee.. but how to throw 2 model in 1 view,  sorry i am beginner in CI. certainly always wrong in making MVC. I must throw to index page

Comment: simply `$this->load->model('model1')`   and `$this->load->model('model2')`    and call functions like `$this->model1->func_name()`  and  `$this->model2->func_name()`